# How to mount usb drive without root or fstab?

Tags: terminal, mount, root, usb-drive

I know this is one of those questions that have been debated up and down the web. But I still want to have some opinions on this. It is about mounting a usb-drive or usb-stick as a normal user.
I mostly work in terminal, and I know the standard procedures: 
- If it's the same drive every time, create an fstab entry 
- If it's an unrecognized drive, use `sudo mount` 
But here is what I do when I am to lazy to write all the paths, type the passwords and deal with the permissions: I type `thunar` (xfce file-manager), click the respective drive in the window and close it again. And the drive is mounted in a predictable place, with read/write permission and I can use it (security nightmare, I know).
Isn't there a terminal alternative for that? I am aware of `usbmount`, but it clashes with another program (`calibre`). So right now I am using something like `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1`, which is ok. But I still have to type my root password. 
And here is a side question: Is the fact that I do all the mounting of different drives under root permissions really making my computer safer? If I mount a potentially dangerous drive, should it really be as root?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** 
@ hschou
Yes, I am using `systemd`. Thanks for the hint to look at `udev`. The output of `dmesg -w` exceeds the maximum character limit. What should I look for?

Comment: Are you using `systemd`? Then it should be possible to use `udev` to handle it. Add the output from `dmesg -w` to your question and I might be able to write the commands.